# Failed to decode param in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Whenever something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/asdd%Asd` is typed in (obviously not a route) I get Failed to decode param. How would I catch this error and redirect to a 404 using a route?

Error middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  //err.status = 404;
  res.redirect('/404');
  next(err);
});
```

package JSON:

```
"engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.4",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing argument in the function signature for your error handler. The first argument is `err` (the error received). Try something like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/404');
  next(err); // <- I don't know enough about ExpressJS to know if this is actually needed. :-D
});
```

Comment: Editing now. Thank you.

Comment: There is no stack trace to be had.

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: The official express generator is junk. Thanks!!